# mysql Opposite of SUBSTRING_INDEX

Tags: mysql, substring

I can select the text string before the @ character:

sample entry in DB: **email@domain.com** , sample output: **email**

with:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(email,'@',1)
```

but what is the command for selecting text string after the @ character ?

Thank you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use a negative value for `count` like this:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(email,'@',-1)
```

See the documentation here:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/string-functions.html#function_substring-index

Comment: This works ONLY if the delimiter is found ONCE in the string. Otherwise you would "lose" parts in the middle. Just saying, in case someone passes by, searching for a solution in case of multiple delimiters.